# Accessing IUpdate2, 3, 4, or 5 from ISearchResult (Windows Update Search)

Tags: vb.net, interface, windows-update

I'm in the process of trying to retrieve Windows Update search results, which are of the type [`IUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386099(v=vs.85).aspx).

The property I want however, is not part of the IUpdate interface. The property I want (`BrowseOnly`), lies within the [`IUpdate3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826506(v=vs.85).aspx) interface.

My question is, how do I access the property in an IUpdate3 interface, from a search result containing `IUpdate`? Or can I alter the interface returned from the search?

Comment: I see from MSDN documentation that `IUpdate3` inherits from `IUpdate` (through `IUpdate2`). Did you try casting to `IUpdate3`? Showing your search code could help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I did not have a reference to WUApi.DLL in my code. Once I put that reference in, I was successfully able to cast my result as an IUpdate3, which gained me access to the BrowseOnly field.

See below (IUpdate3 used around the middle of the code chunk)...

```
''' <summary>
''' Performs a windows update check for any updates that are...
''' A: Not installed
''' B: Not hidden
''' C: Software updates (OS and software, no hardware updates)
''' </summary>
''' <returns>0 on success, 1 on failure</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Function checkForUpdates() As Integer

    Dim updateSession  ' Object to hold our MS Update Session
    Dim updateSearcher ' Object to perform our MS Win Update Search
    Dim results        ' Object to hold our MS Win Update Search Results
    Dim stopWatch As New Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()

    outputWriter.WriteLine("----WINDOWS UPDATES-----@ " & Now, False)
    outputWriter.WriteLine("  -We are beginning our update search. Please note, this may take a few minutes." & _
                           "   On Windows Server 2003 this may take 800 years.", False)

    ' We cannot guarantee the update check will succeed, so use a try catch in case of error.
    Try
        updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
        updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
        results = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")
    Catch ex As Exception
        outputWriter.WriteLine("  ERROR: Something went wrong in our update search. Details below...", False)
        outputWriter.WriteLine("  Error Msg: " & ex.Message, False)
        Return 1
    End Try

    outputWriter.WriteLine("  -Windows update search has successfully completed. Beginning iteration of result set...", False)

    ' Similar to above, we cannot guarantee iterating through our result set will succeed. Use a try catch.
    Try
        Dim totalUpdates = results.Updates.Count
        outputWriter.WriteLine("-----Windows Updates-----@ " & Now, True)
        If results.Updates.Count = 0 Then
            outputWriter.WriteLine("Total Updates: 0", True)
            outputWriter.WriteLine("Important:     0", True)
            outputWriter.WriteLine("Optional:      0", True)
        Else
            Dim imp_updates = 0
            Dim opt_updates = 0
            For i = 0 To totalUpdates - 1
                Dim update = results.Updates.Item(i)
                If CType(update, WUApiLib.IUpdate3).BrowseOnly = True Then ' BrowseOnly is specifically used for whether an update is deemed optional or not (True for optional)
                    opt_updates = opt_updates + 1
                Else
                    imp_updates = imp_updates + 1
                End If
            Next

            outputWriter.WriteLine("Total Updates: " & totalUpdates, True)
            outputWriter.WriteLine("Important:     " & imp_updates, True)
            outputWriter.WriteLine("Optional :     " & opt_updates, True)

        End If
        stopWatch.Stop()
        If stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000 Then
            outputWriter.WriteLine("--------Total Time: " & Math.Round((CDbl(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) / 1000), 2) & " Sec----------------" & vbCrLf, True)
        Else
            outputWriter.WriteLine("--------Total Time: " & stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " MS-------------------" & vbCrLf, True)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        outputWriter.WriteLine("  ERROR: We encountered an issue while iterating through Windows Update Search Results. Details below...", False)
        outputWriter.WriteLine("  Error Msg: " & ex.Message, False)
        Return 1
    End Try

    outputWriter.WriteLine("  -Iteration of Windows Update Search Results has successfully completed.", False)
    outputWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------" & vbCrLf, False)

    ' Clean up our objects.
    updateSession = Nothing
    updateSearcher = Nothing
    results = Nothing

    ' Success!
    Return 0
End Function
```